# 'Concurrent saves are not allowed' with manager.enableSaveQueuing(true)

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Why breeze keeps throwing 'Concurrent saves are not allowed' with   manager.enableSaveQueuing(true) option enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because you're trying to issue multiple saves at the same time.
Breeze's default save option is queuing data for saving.
In your case, you can overwrite the option for allowing concurrent saves as follows:

```
var so =  new breeze.SaveOptions({allowConcurrentSaves: true})
            return manager.saveChanges(null,so) 
                .then(saveSucceeded) // 
                .fail(saveFailed);
```

**EDIT**

Since you are using the "saveQueuing" plugin, Ignore my first Answer since it only applies to concurrent saves.

I'm not aware of how your code works, but you might take some considerations in case of save queuing:

1. You can only issue `manager.saveChanges()` once inside your code.
2. At the server side, override the `BeforeSaveEntity()` method for the sake of the mutual-exclusion lock statement in your new `savechanges()` method, your code may look something like this:

   ```
   public void SaveChanges(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
   {
    lock (__lock) // this will block any try to issue concurrent saves on the same row
   {
   // Saving Operations goes here
   }
   }
   ```

You might want to look at it in the NoDB Sample.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I use [saveQueuing ](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves#savequeuing) plugin,  and as pointed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16043515/995526) saveOptions and savequeuing are mutually exclusive approaches. It seems to be that I need to add rowversion to my model classes in order to use this plugin.

Comment: Ahh! Sorry I misunderstood your question. I'm not sure if the rowversion could solve this issue, I have updated my answer anyway